The path integral representation of the transition amplitude between the vacua of two field theories
The background of the question: PhysRevLett.115.261602.
$
\newcommand\ket[1]{| #1 \rangle} 
\newcommand\braket[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle} 
\newcommand\dif{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm{e}}
$
The task:
We have two Lagrangians $\mathscr L_0$ and $\mathscr L = \mathscr L_0 + \lambda \mathscr O$ where $\lambda$ is a small number (to be specific, a CFT and $\mathscr O$ is marginal).
Note that $\mathscr L_0$ is not necessary free.
Both are $(d + 1)$D spacetime densities.
They would have their own vacua, respectively,
$\ket{\varOmega_0}$ and $\ket{\varOmega(\lambda)}$.
The task is to find the amplitude $\braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0}$.
The approach from PhysRevLett.115.261602 (which I do not understand):
The authors of PhysRevLett.115.261602 give:
$$
    \braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z_0 Z_\lambda}} \int D\phi \,\E^{
        - \int \dif^d x \left(
                \int_{-\infty}^0 \dif \tau \,\mathscr L_0
                + \int_0^{+\infty} \dif \tau \,\mathscr L
        \right)
    } \tag{1}
$$
from which I've already been lost. Later the authors introduce
$$
\ket{\varOmega_\varepsilon (\lambda)}
= \frac{
    \E^{-\varepsilon H_0} \ket{\varOmega (\lambda)}
}{
 \sqrt{\braket{\varOmega (\lambda) | \E^{-2\varepsilon H_0} | \varOmega (\lambda)}}
} \tag{2}
$$
for ``regulation purpose'', and then obtain:
$$
\braket{\varOmega_\varepsilon(\lambda)|\varOmega_0} = \frac{
    \braket{\E^{
        - \int \dif^d x 
                \int^{+\infty}_{\varepsilon} \dif \tau \lambda \mathscr O
    }}
}{
    \braket{\E^{
        - \int \dif^d x \left(
                \int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \dif \tau + \int_\varepsilon^{+\infty} \dif \tau 
        \right) \lambda \mathscr O
    }}
}. \tag{3}
$$
My thoughts and approach:
About Eq. (1)
It seems like the authors use the vacuum functional (The definition of the vacuum state of quantum field by path-integral):
$$
\varPsi[\varphi] 
= \int D\phi_{\phi(t=0) = \varphi} \,
    \E^{
        -\int_{-\infty}^0 \dif \tau \int \dif^d x\, \mathscr L[\phi](\tau)
    },\tag{4}
$$
but this should be understood us the transition amplitude from $\tau = -\infty$ to $\tau = 0$, and to me:
$$
 \braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0} =^? (\text{RHS of Eq. (1)})
\braket{\varOmega(\lambda)(t = +\infty)|\varOmega_0(t = -\infty)}\tag{5}
$$
My thoughts:
At first I tried the Gell-Mann and Low Theorem from that I can only get trivial $\braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0} = \braket{U_{I, \varepsilon} (0, \pm \infty)}/ \braket{U_{I, \varepsilon} (0, \pm \infty)} = 1$.
In fact I do not really know how to understand this $\braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0}$, because the two vacua belong to different Hilbert spaces of the two theories (original and the deformed).
In scattering theories, one ``turns off'' the interaction at both $t \to -\infty$ and $t \to +\infty$, and the vacua at both side shall belong to the same theory (free theory).
But in this case the Hilbert spaces from the both side are different.
Can anyone help me with understanding the approach taken by the authors of PhysRevLett.115.261602?
Or any other idea on how to calculate $\braket{\varOmega(\lambda)|\varOmega_0}$ would be good (precision should reach quadratic ($\lambda^2$) terms).

After some discussion with a friend we came out the following explanations.$
\newcommand\ket[1]{| #1 \rangle}
\newcommand\bra[1]{\langle #1 |}
\newcommand\braket[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle} 
\newcommand\dif{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm{e}}
$
First, consider any state $\ket{\varPsi}$, transformed under the Hamiltonian $H(\lambda) = H_0 - \lambda O$ (here $O := \int \dif x^d\,\mathscr O$) from $\tau = 0$ to $\tau = +\infty$.
Note that the “evolution” is along the real axis of the Euclidean time $\tau$. In terms of real time $t$, it is $-\mathrm i\infty$ to $+ \mathrm i \infty$, hence, the “evolution” is not physical. c.f. How do we perform 'time' translation in Euclidean QFT?
And, since the “evolution” operator
$$
U(0, \tau) =  \E^{- \tau (H_0 - \lambda O)} = \int D\varphi \ket{\varphi, \tau} \E^{-S_\lambda[\varphi]_0^\tau} \bra{\varphi, 0}
$$
decays exponentially as $\tau \to \infty$, only states with the lowest energy (vacuum) survives.
In another word, the “evolution” operator picks out the vacuum of the perturbed theory:
$$
    \E^{- \tau (H_0 - \lambda O)}\ket{\varPsi} \xrightarrow{\tau \to +\infty} \frac {\ket {\varOmega(\lambda)}} {\text{some normalisation factor}}
$$
The normalisation factor can be obtained via:
$$\begin{aligned}
1 = \braket{\varOmega(\lambda) | \varOmega(\lambda)}
 &= \bra \varPsi U_\lambda(-\infty, 0) U_\lambda(0, +\infty) \ket \varPsi 
\\ &= (\text{factor})^2 \int D\varphi\, \E^{- S_\lambda[\varphi]_{-\infty}^0 - S_\lambda[\varphi]_0^{+\infty}} |\braket{\varphi, 0| \varPsi}|^2 = Z_\lambda
\end{aligned}$$
Note that we used $U(\tau, \tau')^\dagger = U(\tau, \tau')$, and $U(-\tau, 0) = U(0, \tau)$ in Euclidean time, assuming $H$ does not explicitly contain $\tau$.
The normalisation condition for $\ket \varPsi$ is also used: $\int D\varphi_{t = 0} |\braket{\varphi, 0| \varPsi}|^2 = 1$. (It seems like there is a little problem here about how to include the integration of $D\varphi$ at $t = 0$ into the $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ integration)
We can do the same for $\tau$ from $-\infty$ to $0$ with unperturbed $H_0$, and eventually get what it is desired (Eq. (1))
This is not satisfactory yet: I am not sure if Euclidean path inegral (PI) works the same as in Minkowski space. Can one really rewrite the “evolution” along the Euclidean time as PI? I will keep the question open inviting further discussion.
